# reactjs: serve the assets from different server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

we have a very bad structure at our servers where each client have his own instance of the project, so there is no unified code base that serves all the clients.

what I want to do is put my react app assets somewhere to be consumed by all instances to avoid repeating the files in every instance. lets say the server DIRs structure is as follow:

- sites/

  - instance1/
  - instance2/
  - instance3/

and inside each instance I have a folder named react-app where the app had been built, so if I want to reach the react-app inside the instance1, the url will be like: [www.mysite.com/sites/instance1/react-app/](http://www.mysite.com/sites/instance1/react-app/)

I want to create a new folder "base-react-app" and put it on the same level of the "sites" folder, this folder will contain all the assets of my app, and inside the "react-app" in each instance I will only put the index.html which have the url of "base-react-app" as it's base url.

This is what I have tried to do:

package.json:

```
{
    "homepage":"http://www.example.com/base-react-app/"
    ...
}
```

.env:

```
REACT_APP_INSTANCE_URL=http://www.example.com/sites/instance1/react-app/
```

then I've defined the routes as follow:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route
            path={`${process.env.REACT_APP_INSTANCE_URL}/`}
            exact
            render={() => <HomePage />}
        />
        ...
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I was able to load the page assets successfully, but the react-router wasn't able to render any component inside the Switch.

any suggestions? can this be done by htaccess redirections?

Comment: React router uses relative path to the host name. So there is no need to pass the whole url. Just path would suffice after the Host name. What i mean is Replace this ```{`${process.env.REACT_APP_INSTANCE_URL}/`}``` with this `/`

Comment: @SaGaR I have already tried this, it didn't work